# Which is the best and appropriate way to write the code in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, coding-style, three-tier

What is the best way to write the code ?

(1) Like directly writing the code in the `button_click()` event.

or

(2) Make the function of that code  which I write in `button_click()` event and write this function in one class and then that function I should call in the `button_Click()` event.Like is it called `three-tier approach` to write the code ?

Like in `button_Click()` event I write the code to save the records in `csv file from datatable`.So I should write that code in `button_Click()` event or I should make one new function and  one new class and write that code in that function which is the new class and calling that function in `button_Click()` event.

This is only one example but **I am talking about all the code written in my application** that which is the `appropriate and best way to write the code` and what are the benefits ? Note that I write the code in Winforms with c#.

Comment: Note that decoupling model and view doesn't mean that you simply extract the code from event handler method, and put exact same code elsewhere. An extra call doesn't suddenly make it "MVC" or even "three-tier" (though that latter is about different things, really). What you need to do is to _model_ the functionality you have spec'd as model classes - in a way that makes sense from _model_ perspective and object-oriented design - and then use that functionality from your event handlers as needed.

Comment: Also have a look at data binding, `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and `IBindingList`/`BindingList<T>`. Quite often, a combination of those implemented on your model classes and wired up to UI through binding obviates the need to write event handlers altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go for the separate function in a different class. You should do that because you'll make the code reusable and create a decent separation between the user interface and application logic. Like this, you could for example change the UI without affecting the rest of the application.

Also take a look at [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you'll understand better the whole idea.

The only situation where i think that the first option should be used is when it does some action that will affect the UI, and still i'll create this in a separate function inside the Form class.

If it's affecting the UI, it should be in the same class because it's related and for example if it's a code to refresh a grid i'll put this in a separate method inside the same Form class because this could be used in different places inside it. So changing the UI has no impact on the application, you just make your code reusable & maintainable.

Comment: @Adrian Faciu,When there is need of changing the UI how it affects the rest of application,please clarify.

Comment: @Harikrishna I've edited my post, i hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on situation.

If you are going to make updates to the Form, then it's better to have the updating code in the Form. However, if there are lots of processing, then surely it's better design to have a separate class handle the job.

It all depends on situation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't want any logic in the event handler, since GUIs tend to provide redundant mechanisms (context menu, menu bar, toolbar, accelerator key) for triggering the same command, and the event signatures aren't compatible for all of these.  Then the question becomes whether your common function should go in the Form class or into the data model.

I often start out with the logic in the Form and then refactor it into model classes as needed.  Many small apps will never get large enough that multiple classes are required for maintainability.  As long as you avoid code duplication (i.e. copy+paste) then refactoring will be straightforward later if you find you need it.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to develop classes for jobs. As it makes your code reusable and it also implement three tier Architecture. The benefit is that it is easy to understand.
The important thing is that, it is only beneficial if you develop your classes appropriately. Develop methods in the class which can be reusable for you.
The another benefit is that it hides the complexity of your code.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know.Just search on Internet...You can get lots of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general approaches to adding structure to code: top down and bottom up.  Top down structure comes from design work that can involve a formal or informal process and pure design artifacts like UML diagrams or functional specs.  The ultimate goal in a top down process is to create classes and interfaces in your code that will provide appropriate structure to make your code maintainable.  This can happen before you write the code, or as part of an iteration, but the idea is that you create the structure first, then create the code.

Bottom up structure comes from refactoring.  For example, start with all your logic in a button click.  When you add a menu item that does the same thing as the button click, move the code for your button click function into a private member function on the form.  When you need the same features in a different part of the application, encapsulate the code and state variables used by your private member function into a class.

I'd recommend using both approaches.  The right mix for your situation depends on the development team (size, location, ability to communicate) and the size of your application.  Generally speaking, large applications require more top down, and on very small applications a minimal amount of top down design is adequate.  But there should always be some high level planning, even for a small app.